# Getting all values which match the nsmallest(5) values in a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I want to pull out all values from a series which have a value found in the n smallest values, as I may have many values with a zero value, but nsmallest(5) only returns 5.

I got this to work, but am wondering if there is a more pythonic way of doing it, like using a lambda, or using a basic in statement?

```
alcohol[[True if a in alcohol.nsmallest(5).values else False for a in alcohol]]  # works, but best way?
```

Comment: Note: every time you see a `True if <bool_value> else False`, it can be replaced with just `<bool_value>`

Comment: @Marat thanks.  Your first <bool_value> comment, this doesnt work:  alcohol[[a in alcohol.nlargest(5) for a in alcohol]].  Ignore me, I forgot to add .values()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

```
>>> alcohol[alcohol <= alcohol.nsmallest(5).max()]
1    46
5    19
6    25
7    17
9    42
dtype: int64
```

Setup

```
np.random.seed(2022)
alcohol = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1, 100, 10))
print(alcohol)

# Output
0    93
1    46
2    50
3    56
4    89
5    19
6    25
7    17
8    54
9    42
dtype: int64
```